# How to write the code recursively?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, dictionary, recursion

I want to convert these pieces of code into smaller one via recursion, but I stuck in place where I'm using `for` loop.

I have the next dictionary: `var structure = [];` with the structure:

```
"path": path,
"children": []
```

I'm filling it by parsing my JSON file. One of the paths from the JSON looks like: `"path": "Assignment_1/src/com",`, so I'm parsing path by `/` and trying to rebuild this structure inside of my `structure` dictionary. The first part, `"path": "Assignment_1/",` I'm putting inside of my structure. The second part `"path": "Assignment_1/src/",` I'm putting inside of the `children` dictionary and so on.

Without recursion I'm doing this:

```
if(path.split("/").length == 2) {
        if(type == "tree") {
            var path0 = path.split("/")[0];
            var path1 = path.split("/")[1];

            for(var j = 0; j < structure.length; j++) {
                var foundPath = structure[j]["path"];

                if(foundPath == path0) {
                    structure[j]["children"].push({
                        "path": path1,
                        "children": []
                    })
                }
            }
        }
    }

    if(path.split("/").length == 3) {
        if(type == "tree") {
            var path0 = path.split("/")[0];
            var path1 = path.split("/")[1];
            var path2 = path.split("/")[2];

            for(var j = 0; j < structure.length; j++) {
                var foundPath = structure[j]["path"];

                if(foundPath == path0) {
                    for(var k = 0; k < structure[j]["children"].length; k++) {
                        var foundPath = structure[j]["children"][k]["path"];

                        if(foundPath == path1) {
                            structure[j]["children"][k]["children"].push({
                                "path": path2,
                                "children": []
                            })
                        }
                    }
                }

                print(structure);
            }
        }
    }
```

Now I want to unify it, so it will automatically go through all folders and fill my `structure` dictionary. I started with `while` loops, but this parts:

```
structure[j]["children"].push({ })
structure[j]["children"][k]["children"].push({ })
```

are too difficult to program. Any help or advice will help me a lot!

**UPDATE**

Input is(one part):

```
{
  "path": "Folder_1/src/com",
  "mode": "040000",
  "type": "tree"
},
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: using `reduce` can help.

Comment: @j.doe please provide sample input/output

Comment: @Jonasw I've added. I hope that will help. If do you need anything, just ask me, please!

Comment: Please don't call `path.split("/")` over and over again. Call it once and save the result.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Create nested object from multiple string paths](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44679971/create-nested-object-from-multiple-string-paths) <= just change *name* to *path* and youre done...

Answer (score 1):

```
var inputs = [
    {
      "path": "Folder_1/src/com",
      "mode": "040000",
      "type":"tree"
    },
    {
      "path": "Folder_1/src/com",
      "mode": "040000",
      "type":"tree"
    },
    {
      "path": "Folder_2/docs/files",
      "mode": "040000",
      "type":"tree"
    }   
],
output = [];

inputs.forEach( function( input ) {
    parse( input.path.split('/'), output );
} );

function parse( input, into ){
    var split = input,
      first = split.shift(),
      newItem = { 'src': first, 'children': [] };     

    if( split.length ){
        parse( split, newItem.children );   
    }   
  if( ! into.find(function(item){return item.src == first } ) ){
        into.push( newItem );
  }
}

console.log( output );
```

[Jfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/o1ka705h/2/)

Although I haven't taken into account `type == tree`, whatever that is.

Comment: thanks for your answer! It works, but it pushes one folder many times into the array, like Folder1, Folder1/children, Folder1/children/children, not only the final result. I'm trying to fix it now

Comment: could you please help me to remove duplicates and join folders with the same parent?

Comment: it seems now it takes only first folders, without children :)

Comment: it seems it works wrong now. It puts only the main(parent) folders, without children =/

Comment: @J.Doe how so? Did you check out my jfiddle? It's working fine for me!